# Replacing a View's contents with the results of an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a counselor portal using Asp.NET and kendo controls in an MVC3 application. I have a button of some view named `AddStudents`. `onClick` of this button a partial view renders and puts the content of that view having this button.

Student form comes on this view but its own contents also comes on the same page, I used an AJAX call with jQuery for doing all this. I want to replace the present contents of the view with incoming contents of the partial view.

```
$("#render").click(function () {
    alert("chawaaaaaa!");
    $.ajax({
        url: "AddStudentsPartial",
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
            $('#partial').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Thats my AJAX function on button click. Can anyone help me to solve this little problem?

Answer (score 0):

Either you replace views content with results content:

```
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
        $('#partial').html($(result).html());
    }
```

or you replace hole view with hole result:

```
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
        $('#partial').replaceWith(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use jquery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method to do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#render").click(function(){
        $("#partial").load("AddStudentsPartial")
    })
});
</script>
```